# Link a domain name without port number to a MEAN stack server hosted by nginx

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, mean-stack, digital-ocean

I have a Ubuntu Server on DigitalOcean, which hosts several websites. I just built a `mean.js` stack app on my mac, and I plan to deploy it to production, thus to this existing server (though I don't know if I need to create another droplet like [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-host-a-mean-stack-app-on-digital-ocean)).

I followed [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-a-mean-js-stack-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server) to install `node.js` and `mongodb`, etc. Then, I cloned my own app from the github:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/softtimur/myapp.git /opt/myapp
cd /opt/myapp
sudo npm install
npm start
```

As a result, in a browser, by entering `https://xxx.xx.xx.xx:3000/#/home`, it communicates well with the server.

Now, I would like to use the domain name I bought from GoDaddy (ie, `myapp.io`) rather than the IP address to communicate to the server.

I have modified the records in DNS of `myapp.io` such that it points to the IP address. As a result, `https://www.myapp.io` leads well to the server, however, it leads to another page set by `nginx` by default.

Then, I set `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.io` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp.io` as follows:

```
server {
        listen 3000;
        listen [::]:3000;

        root /opt/myopp/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name myopp.io;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                client_max_body_size 15M;
        }

        location /phpmyadmin {
           root /usr/share/;
           index index.php index.html index.htm;
           location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                   try_files $uri =404;
                   root /usr/share/;
                   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                   fastcgi_index index.php;
                   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
           }
           location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                   root /usr/share/;
           }
        }
}
```

After restarting `nginx`, `npm start` returns an error: `Port 3000 is already in use`.

Could anyone tell me if this approach is correct? If yes, how could I fix the error, eg., the nginx config file?

**Edit 1:** In `/etc/nginx/sites-avaiable/default`, I have

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name xxx.xx.xx.x;
```

Comment: Do you have `ipv6only=off` in any of your other configuration files?

Comment: Please see **Edit 1**

Comment: Is there a spurious file (maybe a backup file) in `sites-enabled` that might cause the `listen 3000` to be read twice.

Comment: In `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.io` (which is also `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp.io`), it listens to `3000`. Besides that, in this mean-stack app, in `www`, it also listens to `3000` `var server = https.createServer(config, app).listen(3000);`, so that `https://xxx.xx.xx.xx:3000/#/home` works before the nginx files are set...

Comment: Are you saying that you have another process listening on port 3000? If so, why do you need `nginx` to listen on port 3000 also (and BTW - that will not work)

Comment: If I don't set those two nginx files, `https://www.myapp.io` (without specifying 3000) leads well to the server, but it leads to another page set by nginx by default. So I don't know how to make `https://www.myapp.io` equivalent to `https://xxx.xx.xx.xx:3000/#/home`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is reverse proxy from `//www.myapp.io` to `//xxx.xx.xx.xx:3000`. This is achieved by listening on port 80 (or 443) and using `proxy_pass` to connect with your service running on port 3000. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

For an `http` server, you could use:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myopp.io;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_set_header    Accept-Encoding     "";
        proxy_set_header    Proxy               "";
        proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
```

Obviously you are using `https` which could be implemented by changing your service to use `http` on port 3000. Installing your certificates and terminating SSL using `nginx`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) for more.

Comment: Thank you, I will test it... will the content of the config file you listed be all that we need? In my version, I also have `\.php$`, `/phpmyadmin` and `error_page`, etc. I don't know if they are necessary... Do you have a clean template for mean-stack app?

Comment: It's a basic example - you may need to improve it with caching, [web sockets](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/) and SSL termination.

Comment: I guess `root /opt/myopp/;` is still necessary to point to the physical location of the app?

Comment: Nginx does not need this unless you need it to serve static files. In which case you would need to add more location blocks anyway.

Comment: I finally made the provided code work: for me, **`server_name myopp.io;` must be `server_name myopp.io *.myopp.io;`**. Then I copied `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.io` to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp.io`, restarted nginx, `npm start` in `/opt/myopp/`, cleaned the browser history, as a result `http://www.myapp.io/#/home` leads to the right server page (ie, `http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:3000/#/home`).